# Can´t SSH into a Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-4, ssh, connection

I am experiencing problems with SSHing into a home Pi that I have.
When trying to SSH into it I get this error:

```
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset
```

When using the -v option I get this output:

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.2 [192.168.1.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\rakyx/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\rakyx/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\rakyx/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\rakyx/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\rakyx/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\rakyx/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\rakyx/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\rakyx/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\rakyx/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\rakyx/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset
```

The server is ping-able and replies instantly. The IP is correct (at least my router thinks that?)
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very short on details (wrt what you did to setup your SSH keys), but it ***sounds like*** you have somehow opted for SSH key authentication (instead of passwords), but failed to either generate your SSH public & private keys, **or** transfer your public key to the server (Pi) using the `ssh-copy-id` command:

```bash
$ ssh-copy-id user@192.168.1.2  

# where `user` is your username on RPi, 192.168.1.2 is the RPi address in your Question
```

EDITS:

If this doesn't help, or you get errors suggesting you haven't actually *generated* your SSH keys, there are two (2) alternatives:

1. Generate SSH keys on your client machine (Windows, it seems). If you don't know how to do that, [choose a tutorial from this list.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ssh+key+generation+in+windows&t=ffab&atb=v297-1&ia=web).
2. Attempt a password-only login (from your client):

```bash
$ ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no user@192.168.1.2
```

Comment: I clean installed raspbian on it and nothing changed. I enabled ssh with passwords in the imager. But I will try the command you set

Comment: I ran the command and it said this:
`/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: No identities found`

Comment: @dvmc:    I don't know why password didn't work, but will guess that something was overlooked??  Anyway - let's continue with SSH key authentication: The error msg in yr comment suggests you have not generated SSH keys. See # 1. under EDITS in my answer. Again - ***please edit your question*** to add information. ALSO: [read this](https://serverfault.com/questions/98289/ssh-doesnt-ask-for-password-gives-permission-denied-immediately)

Comment: The pubkeyauth=no worked! Thanks.